# Yii Model CGridView including column with Yii-User Profile Field data

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

I'm looking to enable search criteria in a model for a related module's model.
Here's an example to explain what I mean:

- I have a 'Product' model which contains 'user_id'.
- In Yii-user I created a Custom Profile Field called 'brand'.
- I have a CGridView (with Search/Filter functionality) in my Product model's index view which lists all products.
- I want to add the 'brand' profile field (which is a custom Profile Field made with Yii-User) to the CGridView columns allowing people to filter and search the grid view by 'brand'.

I added the following code to my Product model relations:

```
public function relations()
{
            Yii::import('application.modules.user.models.*');
    Yii::app()->getModule('user');
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
    );
}
```

And then adding this to the Product model's search criteria:

```
$criteria->compare('user.brand', $this->user->profile->brand, true);
```

This however yields no positive results.

I'm not sure if I'm going the right direction here. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you put the below lines in 'relations()' function?

```
Yii::import('application.modules.user.models.*');
Yii::app()->getModule('user');
```

You need put 'brand' how a public or private attribute on 'Product' model. This attribute is not persistent, only use for the get the filter form value.

Then use like this:

```
$criteria->compare('user.brand', $this->brand, false);
```

And is possible that you need put 'brand' attribute on the 'rules()', on the array() with 'on'=>'search'.